# Describing the kernel of a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[T]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

This is a question from an (old) exam at my university on Rings and Modules. It's not part of any ongoing assignment.

We are given a homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[X,Y] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[T]$, defined by $\phi(X) = T^2, \phi(Y) = T^5$.

The first part of the question is whether $\phi$ is surjective, and it's easy to show it's not: since any monic monomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$ is of the form $X^iY^j$, and $\phi (X^iY^j) = T^{2i+5j}$, so for example $T^3 \in \mathbb{Z}[T]$ cannot be an element of the Im$(\phi)$.

The second part of the question is where I'm having doubts: It says to "**Find a simple description of the ideal of the kernel of $\phi$**."

**My approach**:I try to find an iff condition for an element of $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$ being an element of the kernel. First I note that any $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$ may be written as $\sum_{i,j = 0}^n a_{i,j}X^iY^j$, where $a_{i,j} \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $i,j$ range independently over $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $\phi$ is a homomorphism, we have $$\phi(f) = \sum_{i,j = 0}^n a_{i,j}\phi(X^iY^j) = \sum_{i,j = 0}^n a_{i,j}T^{2i + 5j}$$

At this point, we have $f\in \text{Ker}(\phi) \iff \sum_{i,j = 0}^n a_{i,j}T^{2i + 5j} = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}[T]$. After applying the homomorphism, the coefficients of different monic monomials in $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$ may become the same monic monomial in $\mathbb{Z}[T]$. For example, $\phi (X^8Y^3) = \phi(X^3Y^5) = T^{31}$.

Now I try to identify monic monomials in $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$ that reduce to the same monomial in $\mathbb{Z}[T]$ under $\phi$. We note that $\phi (X^iY^j) = \phi (X^aY^b) \iff 2i+5j = 2a+5b$. For some fixed $i,j$, consider the solution set in $a,b$, that is the solution set $\{(a,b): 2i+5j = 2a+5b\} = \{(a,b): 2(i-a)+5(j-b) = 0\}$. Now this is just a linear diophantine equation of the form $2x+5y = 0$, so we get that $a_n = i-5n$ and $b_n = j+2n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now the iff condition becomes $$f\in \text{Ker}(\phi) \iff \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_{i-5n,j+2n} = 0$$

for every $i,j$ ranging from $0 \text{ to } n$, and such that we interpret $a_{s,t} = 0$ whenever $s$ or $t$ is negative, or whenever $a_{s,t}$ is not a coefficient of some term of $f$.

As an example, if $f = a_{3,5}X^3Y^5 + a_{8,3}X^8Y^3$, then $\phi(f) = 0 \iff a_{3,5}+a_{8,3} = 0$.

---

I believe the above does indeed characterise the elements of the kernel of $\phi$, but it feels very clunky and I think there must be a better way of approaching the problem. Particularly, I didn't use part (a) where $\phi$ is shown to not be surjective, and my approach doesn't seem very 'algebraic'. Is there a better answer/approach?

Comment: We can see immediately that $X^5-Y^2$ is in the kernel. The trick is showing that $\langle X^5-Y^2\rangle$ is all of the kernel (which, to be perfectly honest, I'm not 100% certain of, because I haven't actually checked).

Comment: In particular, show $$\sum_{n}a_{i-5n,j+2n}=0$$ if and only if $$\sum_n a_{i-5n,j+2n} X^{i-5n}Y^{j+2n}$$ is a multiple of $X^5-Y^2.$

Comment: I would rewrite your condition as “For every $n\geq 0$, $$\sum_{i,j\mid2i+5j=n} a_{i,j}=0.”$$ It is really the same, but a bit cleaner, and doesn’t need to know what that collection of $(i,j)$ pairs looks like, at first. The left side is just the coefficient for $T^n.$

Comment: "Particularly, I didn't use part (a) where $ϕ$ is shown to not be surjective" Surjectivity and injectivity are usually independent in algebra. For finite dimensional vector spaces, they are very much connected. Not so in the more general context of groups and rings. It is entirely as expected that you didn't use part (a).

Comment: @Arthur I didn't really think to try to show the kernel was principal, is there any reason we can expect it to be the case? Also with regards to not using surjectivity, that was mostly down to exam questions typically using previous results, but I learned something new!

Comment: @masiewpao Mostly experience and intuition. And also a general wish that we are lucky. Turns out in this case we are. There is probably some dimension theory that can back it up if you want to be theoretical about it (there are theorems not unlike the rank-nullity theorem of linear algebra, and we do lose one variable "dimension" as we go from $\Bbb Z[X, Y]$ to $\operatorname{im}(\phi)$, so having a one-generator kernel to make up for that is expected, although it's not always so clear-cut).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I would consider the standard "more algebraic" approach:

$X^5-Y^2$ is clearly contained in the kernel of $\phi$. That means that we can "insert" $\Bbb Z[X,Y]/\langle X^5-Y^2\rangle$ between $\Bbb Z[X,Y]$ and $\Bbb Z[T]$ like so:
$$
\Bbb Z[X,Y]\to\Bbb Z[X,Y]/\langle X^5-Y^2\rangle\to \Bbb Z[T]
$$
in such a way that the first homomorphism here is the canonical quotient map, and the second homomorphism (say $\phi'$) is "still" $\phi'(X+\langle X^5-Y^2\rangle)= T^2$ and $\phi'(Y+\langle X^5-Y^2\rangle)= T^5$ (I will skip the coset notation from here on out). Finally, the composition of these two maps is $\phi$. Algebraists summarize all this by saying that $\phi$ "factors through" $\Bbb Z[X,Y]/\langle X^5-Y^2\rangle$.

We want to know whether $\phi'$ is injective. Because if it is, we have found the entire kernel. To do this, we take an element in the kernel of $\phi'$, and show that it must be $0$.

How is this different from working in $\Bbb Z[X,Y]$? Note that we can make all elements of $\Bbb Z[X,Y]/\langle X^5-Y^2\rangle$ have a particular form, namely where there is no $Y$ term with higher exponent than $1$ (remember that $Y^2=X^5$ in the quotient ring). This makes things *much* easier.

Let $f\in\ker \phi'$ be written on that form. So we have
$$
f(X,Y)=f_0(X)+Yf_1(X)
$$
for some single-variable integer-coefficient polynomials $f_0, f_1$. Now we apply $\phi'$. We get
$$
0=\phi'(f)(T)=f(T^2,T^5)=f_1(T^2)+T^5f_2(T^2)
$$
It isn't difficult to see that we *must* have $f_1=f_2=0$.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very nice answer. I think I follow the logic up to the end of the proof, but I am not quite sure how we go from the injectivity of $\phi '$ to knowing the kernel of $\phi$?

Comment: @masiewpao There is a bijective correspondence between the ideals of $\Bbb Z[X, Y]/\langle X^5-Y^2\rangle$, and the ideals of $\Bbb Z[X, Y]$ that contain $\langle X^5-Y^2\rangle$. The kernel of $\phi'$ corresponds to the kernel of $\phi$ in this way. The zero ideal of $\Bbb Z[X, Y]/\langle X^5-Y^2\rangle$ corresponds to $\langle X^5-Y^2\rangle\subseteq \Bbb Z[X, Y]$ this way. If $\phi'$ is injective, then the kernel of $\phi'$ **is** the zero ideal of $\Bbb Z[X, Y]/\langle X^5-Y^2\rangle$. Then I know that these two pairs of corresponding ideals are really just one pair.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, you want to find generators for the kernel. The most obvious generator is $X^5-Y^2.$ Do you need more?

Now note that:

$$X^{5n}\equiv Y^{2n}\pmod {X^5-Y^2}$$
So:

$$X^{i-5n}Y^{j+2n}\equiv X^iY^{j}\pmod{X^5-Y^{2}}\tag1$$
when $i-5n\geq 0.$

This is because $$\begin{align}X^{i-5n}Y^{j+2n}&=\left(X^{i-5n}Y^j\right)Y^{2n}\\&\equiv \left(X^{i-5n}Y^j\right) X^{5n}\pmod{X^5-Y^2}\\&=X^iY^j\end{align}$$
Use (1) inductively to show that:

$$\sum_{n} a_{i-5n,j+2n}X^{i-5n}Y^{j+2n}\equiv\left(\sum_n a_{i-5n,i+2n}\right) X^iY^j\pmod {X^5-Y^2}$$

So:

$$\sum_n a_{i-5n,j+2n}=0$$ if and only if

$$\sum_{n} a_{i-5n,j+2n}X^{i-5n}Y^{j+2n}\equiv0\pmod {X^5-Y^2}\tag 2$$

Use (2) to show that $p(X,Y)$ is in the kernel if and only if $p(X,Y)$ is divisible by $X^5-Y^2.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In the very last step, is the conclusion simply that $p$ is in the kernel iff the sums of coefficients are zero, so by (2) it must by an element of $(X^5 - Y^2)$?

Comment: Well, we know any multiple of $X^5-Y^2$ is in the kernel, since $X^5-Y^2$ is in the kernel. And you showed if $p$ is in the kernel, the sum of the coefficients is zero, which I've shown means $p$ is divisible by $X^5-Y^2.$ So yes, any element of the kernel is an element of $\langle X^5-Y^2\rangle.$

Comment: Thank you very much!